# VS2010/VS2012 default Doctypes and which to use to be future-proof

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html, xhtml, doctype, visual-studio-2012

I was wondering why VS2010 and VS2012 use different doctype declarations for masterpages and webforms.

i.e. VS2010 uses the "XHTML 1.0 Strict" doctype for masterpages and the "XHTML 1.0 Transitional" doctype for webforms.

VS2012 uses HTML5 "DOCTYPE html" for masterpages and adds the XHTML namespace (xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml") to the body tags of web forms.

Is there any reason for this behaviour?

I am trying to find out what doctype I should use for a relaunch of a website. I want to support older IE and FF versions too but I do not want to use the new HTML5 Tags/Attributes (at the moment,  but propably I will use them somewhen in the future).

The website is developed in VS2010 with ASP.NET 4.0 but I will change to VS2012 with ASP.NET 4.5 as soon as possible. And this is my very problem which unsettles me. As mentioned the two versions use different doctype declarations and now I do not know what to do to be future-proof and tolerant of older browsers.

thanks in advance for your answers

PS: I do not want to use MIME types other than text/html

Answer (score 0):

I used to stringantly stick to Xhtml 1.0 strict as a rule, however these days i'm using `<!DOCTYPE html>` for all websites.

for me its probably the best way to future proof your doctype, and supporting the new tags in older browsers is easy if you use a HTML5 shim that provides compatibility through javascript for the new tags.

Comment: I am tending to use the HTML5 doctype too but I am not sure if the head of my department is so lucky about it (especially because of the javascript workaround you mentioned). I guess you talk about the fix in this article (http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/).

The thing is, that the website I am talking about is quite big and has a lot of visits. So I have to rely on a good representation in nearly all browsers.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the html5 doctype and avoiding the new html5 tags, most tags are interpreted in an xhtml strict kind of way. so instead of using `<body><header>foo</header></body>` you could use `<body><div class="header">bar</div></body>` as a pointer you could always get microsoft virtual PC (free) and download IE6 and IE7 images to get a more accurate picture of how it would work.